# search for file extensions with ~ in finder

Tags: finder, search, file-extensions

i ran a script to change a tiff image, now it created the new image but kept the original with the file extension ".tif~".  Is there any way to search for all of the files in Finder or in another way with the .tif~ extension to remove them all?

I tried searching for system files and including invisible files in the search.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Finder hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Spotlight interface (without requiring a string to search for).
2. Hit the search parameter dropdown (by default "Kind"), select Name.
3. Select 'matches' in next dropdown.
4. Type `tif~` in the text box.

You could select `Kind → Other` and insert `tif~`, but does not work that way.

Additionally,  you could search for it on the Terminal type the following in your home directory:

```
find . -name "*.tif~"
```

Comment: i tried Name, but that doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I updated my answer. The terminal command works, if don't is because you don't have any files with that extension.

Comment: If you know the Folder select it first, if not select your hard drive to search all (.tiff)